# cleartool Unable to determine modified elements in "<UUID>" in stream "<stream name>"

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am using ClearCase UCM - Multisite (version 7.x) When I rebase a partcular stream, I get following error.

```
cleartool  Unable to determine modified elements in  "<UUID>" in stream  "<stream name>"

Advancing to baseline "temp2.6922" of component "cframework_src"
...
Updating rebase view's config spec...
Creating integration activity...
Setting integration activity...
Merging files...
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine modified elements in vob "14828f48.3c1411d6.a3a2.00:01:80:c3:ed:84" in stream  "stream_name".
cleartool: Error: Unexpected error in rebase.
cleartool: Error: Unable to perform merge.
cleartool: Error: Unable to perform integration.
cleartool: Error: Unable to rebase stream "<stream_name>".
```

---

The magic uid somehow relate to a Vob family uuid-- listed below

```
Tag: \cframework_src
  Global path: \\svr-inh-net-01\ccvobstore2\cframework_src.vbs
  Server host: svr-inh-cc-02
  Access: public
  Mount options: 
  Region: MGI_WIN
  Active: YES
  Vob tag replica uuid: 510b4e21.ecef11df.8889.00:01:84:38:25:75
Vob on host: svr-inh-cc-02
Vob server access path: /project/ccvobstore2/cframework_src.vbs
Vob family uuid:  14828f48.3c1411d6.a3a2.00:01:80:c3:ed:84
Vob replica uuid: 510b4e21.ecef11df.8889.00:01:84:38:25:75
Vob registry attributes: replicated
```

---

What is the real maning of the error? How can I fix this?

More info

There are other streams which under same pvob.  They all work fine.
Sync is complete - no errors - anywhere.

What is puzzling is lack of information in error logs and clearcase logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution resolved the issue:

canceled the current rebase

After clearing the rebase, issued the following commands against
the branch type:

```
cleartool checkvob -hlink -f brtype:<stream name>@\***pvob           
cleartool checkvob -hlink -f brtype:<stream name>@\childvob
cleartool checkvob -global -acquire -f brtype:<stream name>@\***pvob
```

This repaired issues with the branch type.

After performing this step, issued "cleartool chstream -generate" 
or sycn the stream with the project from the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually linked to a Vob not declared in the current region, either the \cframework_src itself, or one of its adminVob/PVob (since it is an UCM Vob).

Try a `cleartool descr -l vob\cframework_src` to see all the linked AdminVob and check if they are registered.

Make also sure it isn't related to right issue when accessing to a specific element (file or directory), by doing a `cleartool ls` in the destination view (the one where the rebase is in progress).

If it is limited to a specific stream, do a:

```
cleartool descr -l stream:aStream@\aPVob
```

Compare its output to the same command for another Stream (which works), in order to check if there is a permission issue (like a "Group NOBODY", because it was created with the wrong `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  Looks  like this one require IBM support- contacted.

Comment: @Jayan Good call. I am interested in their answer ;)